# React Native - Add Background Color/Opacity To Entire Screen But to Child Component?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to achieve something like below where a child component will have no background color/opacity that is applied from the parent?

Unfortunately the solution right now is to use an image. But that only works as long as I plan to create an app only for the iPhone X. Not good.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure, just give the child component a color

Comment: Wrap the child in an opaque parent that's the same size?

Comment: @Kai that's the thing though, I'm not trying to give the child any sort of color. I'd like it to be transparent so the background image is fully visible. Like the flower example  from above.

Comment: Have you tried setting `opacity: 0`?

Comment: @Kai so set the parent's opacity to say black @ 0.8 and the child's opacity to black @ 0?

Comment: Here' what that looks like https://i.imgur.com/nw2O25k.png. I made the parent and child 70% of the screen so you can see the background image.

Comment: @stever see my above comment. Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: I think I understood the problem differently.  I thought you did not want to display any inherited opacity.

Comment: @stever no no...you're correct. I don't want the child to show behind it the parent's opacity. Using the flower example from above, I'd like the parent to have an opacity but then the child will not inherit that. As a result you should be able to see the flowers inside the child component clearly. Basically, the way the iPhone XR looks in the above flower example.